# 要件定義にプログラムが何言語を使うのは何の要件ですか？

Tags: 詳細設計

例え、プログラムがC言語で作ります。
要件として、何要件に分類されますでしょうか？

- 機能性に関する要件
- 信頼性に関する要件
- 使用性に関する要件
- 効率性に関する要件
- 保守性に関する要件
- 移植性に関する要件
- 安全性に関する要件

ご教示をお願いします。

Comment: おそらく参考文献 https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4903477134

Comment: すみません、この辺詳しくは知りませんが、全部に当てはまるような気がします。

Answer (score -1):

全ての用件に満たす言語の採用としてC言語という結論に至ります。アーキテクチャ設計です。
また、ご教授→ご教示です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。若し顧客がC言語を使用するという要望がある場合はどうしますか？

Comment: C言語にしたい要望の理由はなんでしょうか。開発スキル（C要員が多い）や、既存流用したいなど、何か理由があると思います。なんと言われてますか。

Comment: 言われていません。単純に客側からそのようなリクエストがもしあれば、要件仕様書をどう書くかという疑問です。

Comment: あるべき論で言うとなぜC言語のリクエストがあるかを特定する（理由）工程が要件定義です。

Comment: 書くことが目的ではなく、ニーズ理解をすべきです。理由なくC決めうちならば、前提条件ですね。C決めうちで考えた場合の、各要件を論じます。たとえばCに重大なセキュリティホールがあったとしても、顧客要望の前提条件によってCを採用しているので、ベンダー責なし。など。